# resultset.getString returns dummy values

Tags: jsp

i am trying to get values from result set in jsp
but i am getting all dummy values.

here is my code

```
LibraryDBHelper db=null;
Connection con=null;
Statement st=null;
ResultSet rs2=null;
String name;
public DatabaseManager() {
}

@Override
public String login(String id, String pwd) {
    try {
        con=db.getConnection();
        String sql="select username from users where userid="+id+" and password='"+pwd+"'";
        Statement ps=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(sql);


            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("hellors");
                name=rs.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(name);
    return name;
}
```

i tried executing the sql in mysql(phymyadmin) its giving results like this
 here is my sql query 
`SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE userid=1000101 and password='first'`

[image]

here is the snapshot of the eclipse with dummy values

[image]

Comment: Mandatory comment: using string concatenation like that may leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: name=rs.getString(1) return first column and it is integer value. rs.getString(3) try please

Comment: rs.getString(2)..try with this.

Comment: prepared statement also does not work i tried with it but of no use still getting same kind of output